# GIT: ignoring some directories, but not the others

Tags: git, gitignore

How can one ignore some directories and not others, assuming they both have the same name?

Suppose you have a directory called "report" where you store results of your `jUnit` test case runs (and don't want to track them). Additionally, somewhere deep down directory tree you have a folder called report (contents of which you do want to track)

`.gitignore` currently contains "report". As a result, all folders named "report" are ignored.

**How can i explicitly say "ignore this folder but not anything else named like it"?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the gitignore manual:

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

So in your `.gitignore` just specify `/report`

Answer (score 1):

git treats files without a slash as a glob for all files in any directory which matches.

To match only files in the current directory you can precede **report** with a '/'.

like :

```
/report
```

For more details [see the gitignore manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)